# After the monkey head approaches the cube, the cube bounces. How to use geometric nodes to make it?

Tags: python

After the monkey head approaches the cube, the cube bounces. How to use geometric nodes to make it?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Until someone smarter ...

[image]
[image]

[image]

Notes:

- *Store Named Attribute* node is there just to see frames where Suzanne affects cube (pink color).
- *Geometry Proximity* is not probably the best solver for activating animation ... the problem is not activating, but fact that duration of cube animation depend on monkey position, that doesnt have to fit any scenario.
- back and forth anim is done by *Sine* math node

... Simulation nodes would works probably better.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: If answer solved your issue consider mark answer as accepted. Thank you keep this site organised https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour