# When the monkey's head touches the cube, the cube bounces and is implemented using geometric nodes

Tags: python

When the monkey's head touches the cube, the cube bounces and is implemented using geometric nodes.
[image]

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: Need to achieve automatic bouncing of the cube, after being touched by a monkey head

Comment: Cube auto bounce

Comment: Cube automatically bounces when touched

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice! https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/306599/after-the-monkey-head-approaches-the-cube-the-cube-bounces-how-to-use-geometri. If you don't get an answer, read [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit and improve your original question rather than posting it again.